# Error Count - PHP

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a form which has email as field name. What I am trying to do is if the email is it no equal to `$emailToCheck` is not equal to `$_POST['email']`, it should throw an error first time. The second time if the user enters wrong email id again it should always redirect to `"error.htm"` even if the page refreshes.

It doesn't work the form always shows even if the email id is entered wrong twice.

```
  <?php

if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email="website@test.com";
    if($email!=$_POST['email'])
    {
        $count="1";
    }
    if($count=="2"){
    header("Location: /error.htm");
        exit(0); 
    }
}

if($count!="2"){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Form</a></h1>
        <form id="form_1123848" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Form</h2>
            <p> <input type="text" name="email" value="" /></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li class="buttons">
                                    <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 


    </body>
</html>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to use sessions in order to keep the counter between requests: read here http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here: 
 1. You are defining `$count` as a string, and never incrementing it. If you look over your code, `$count` is getting specifically set to `1` every time there is a mismatch. How is supposed to ever get to `2`? 
 2. Furthermore, data here is stateless. How is the script supposed to know what `$count` was set to on the previous call? You need to also set `$count` as a session variable so that the script will know what its previous value.

You should try updating your code to something similar to this:

```
// Check if `email` passed in POST request:
if ($_POST['email']) {
  $email = "website@test.com"; //Manually define expected email address.

  // Check if provided email does *not* match the expected email:
  if ($email !== $_POST['email']) {
    // Record the mismatch attempt in session and increment:
    if (!($_SESSION['incorrectEmailCount'])) {
      // If this is the first mismatch, define the session variable, and set to 1. 
      $_SESSION['incorrectEmailCount'] = 1;
    } else {
      // Session variable already set due to previous mismatch. Increment it.
      $_SESSION['incorrectEmailCount']++;
    }
  }
  // If user entered incorrect email more than once:
  if ($_SESSION['incorrectEmailCount'] > 1) { 
    // Redirect to error page and stop execution. 
    header("Location: /error.htm");
    exit(0); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in on line 10

Comment: Gotta work with me here a bit buddy, can you not figure out the reason for that error and attempt to fix it? I've updated the code, the `if` statement was missing a closing parenthesis sign.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to php, learning oi think i do not need this now right if ($count <= 2):

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The default behavior would be to display the HTML, unless the script exits prematurely due to 2 or more mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

Once the form is submitted, the page reloads, resetting the counter. In order to actually count, you need to provide that value in the form and pass it along to the PHP when the form is submitted.

```
<?php

// Try to get the amount of attempts from the POSTed data
$count = isset($_POST['count']) ? $_POST['count'] : 0;

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email = "website@test.com";

  if ($email != $_POST['email']) {
      $count++;
  }

  if ($count == 2) {
    header("Location: /error.htm");
  }
}

if ($count <= 2):
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>

    <body id="main_body" >
        <div id="form_container">
            <h1><a>Form</a></h1>
            <form id="form_1123848" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                <!-- Let the POST data know this is the x attempt -->
                <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $count; ?>">

                <div class="form_description">
                    <h2>Form</h2>
                    <p> <input type="text" name="email" value="" /></p>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="buttons">
                        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Also, your coding style is far from consistent. Try to work on that!

Comment: This would work yes, however it will not do anything really (blank screen) if it's more than 2. So, it's best to change the `if ($count == 2)` to `if ($count >= 2)` - *Just saying* ;-) if ever they want to echo rather than redirect.